# Style the background of a Vaadin 14 Dialog

Tags: java, vaadin14

I want to change the background-color of a Vaadin 14 Dialog. I did not get it how to do it. There is no method for it. The id is "overlay" and the color is #3b85e6.

How to do that? I only managed to add styles to the content, but i want to change the background.

Answer (score 2):

In your Java code, your view class, add import for styles.

```
@CssImport(value = "./styles/my-dialog.css", themeFor = "vaadin-dialog-overlay")
```

And create file "frontend/styles/my-dialog.css", whos content is

```
:host {
    background: #3b85e6;
}
```

Comment: Although this answer has upvotes, it does not work at my side. The complete page gets blue and the dialog stays white in the middle. Before the dialog was not covering the whole page. What did i wrong? I copied and pasted like all the other it experts out there.

Comment: I wanted only the dialog not the whole page to have a different color.